# Prevent function from starting second time, if first is not finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a code that throws an element to up with an acceleration(works like gravity) value and falls down when changed_lenght reaches to zero;

"mouseenter" is triggering this function. When mouse leaves and enters quickly the function starts over and over again, and not stoping the previous ones so it looks so bad.

I wonder is there any way to check if previous one was ended before starting the function. Or any other solution that can help me ?

here is my **JS codes**:

```
$('#outher').mouseenter(function moveone(){

    var t = 0;
    var v = 20;
    var p = 275;
    var a = 5;
    var moveoneint = setInterval(jump, 50);
    function jump(){
            t++;
            x = (v*t) - (0.5 * a * t * t);
            p = (p - x);
            if(x <= 0){
                clearInterval(moveoneint);
                t = 0;
                var movetwo = setInterval(fall, 50);
                function fall(){
                    t++;
                    x = (0.5 * a * t * t );
                    p = (p + x);
                    document.getElementById('inner').style.top = p + 'px';
                    if(p >= 275){
                        clearInterval(movetwo);
                    }
                }


            }
            else{               
                document.getElementById('inner').style.top = p + 'px';      
        }
    }
});
```

and Here is a **Fiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/ctarimli/TJte8/

Comment: you should think about using jQuery `animate()` method, coupled with `stop()` method and easing effect (not natively supported but many plugin hanlde it)

Comment: how can I achieve this gravity effect with "animate" method? As I know animate uses same speed, but I want it to be get slower to the up and get faster to the down

Comment: search for easing effects, that's basically what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply remove the `mouseenter` handler until the animation has completed.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TJte8/2/)

Basically,

```
var $outher = $('#outher');

var onMouseEnter = function() {
    $outher.off('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);

    // do all your animation logic, and once complete...
    $outher.on('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);
};

$outher.on('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);
```

Comment: I think thats what I am looking for, actually my code is bit longer than I wrote here. I will try that in my code. I will write the result

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to third-party library code, then [throttle /debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) will do what you want. Note that the page mentions jQuery, but the library does not actually require jQuery.

In particular, look at the examples for the $.throttle method.

Comment: @jmar777's suggestion helped me for now but I will look yours, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `is` to check if div is animating

```
if(!$('.inner').is(':animated'))
{
     //Your code
}
```